# How to prove how many ireducible polynomials are in a polynomial ring over a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Can someone help me out with some problem concerning the cardinaliy of ireducible polynomials in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$?

Here first why the problem appeared,

I want to prove that $card(max(p\mathbb Z[x]))=\infty$ where $max(p\mathbb Z[x])$ denotes the set of all maximal ideals containing $p\mathbb Z[x]$ for some prime $p$. So I showed in a first step that $p\mathbb Z[x] + f\mathbb Z[x]$ is an maximal ideal iff $\pi(f)$ is an ireducible polynomial and where $\pi:\mathbb Z[x]\rightarrow(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$ is the canonical projection.

If now there exists infinitely many ireducible polynomials in $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$ i could use the fact that $\pi$ is surjecive to conclude that $card(max(p\mathbb Z[x]))=\infty$ since $p\mathbb Z\subset p\mathbb Z[x] + f\mathbb Z[x] \;\;\forall f\in\mathbb Z[x]$.

But I am not even sure if there are...

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with Euclid's proof for the infinity of prime numbers? The same proof works in the case of polynomials in $(\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z})[x]$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So you mean the proof is: Assume there are only finitely many irreducible polynomials, lets say $p_1,...,p_n\in(\mathbb Z /p \mathbb Z)[x]$. This implies that $p_1\cdots p_n+1$ is either irreducible, what would contradict the assumption or there exists an irreducible polynomial $q\in(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$ such that $q$ divides $p_1\cdots p_n+1$. But this means that $q$ divides 1 which is not possible?

Comment: That's the one. For full credit you do need to justify some basic steps (division algorithm of polynomials and its consequences).

Comment: If I find time today I will try to post the complete proof but  already a big thank you to you!